# Slowdown ajax requests for keyup-event of a text-field

Tags: javascript, jquery

`#target` is a input text field. As the user types something into it, I want to check via an ajax request (function `ajaxSend`), if the value is correct. I want to slow down the ajax-check a little bit, as if somebody is typing very fast I do not have to check for each keyup, but i.e. for each 500ms.

The inout field is created dynamically, that's why I have to delegate the keyup event.

I don't know, what I'm doing wrong, but there are still multiple requests for each keyup:

```
$('body').off('keyup', '#target').on('keyup', '#target', function() { 
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value) setTimeout( ajaxSend(value), 500 );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. Has to be:

```
if (value) setTimeout( function() { ajaxSend(value)}, 500 );
```